# Android Studio - How to configure Android Studio to ask about the project to open when he start?

Tags: android, android-studio

When I open `Android Studio IDE` they open the last project that I opned :

I want Android Studio to ask me about the project to open, How do I do it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to **un-check** one thing that is checked by default settings of **Android Studio**.

Do it like this,

Go to **File -> Settings** or press **(Ctrl+Alt+S)**

Under the tab of **IDE Settings** select **General** Option from left side of window

Settings will be appeared on right side, now just **Un-check** ***Reopen last project on startup***

And then click **Apply** and **OK** button at bottom.

Now your project will be closed everytime you close Android-Studio, so it will open a window to select a project

Comment: Not copying your answer friend, I edit it before you post, now two answer are same i deleted my answer.

Comment: Updated answer for finding 'Resopen last project on startup' in Android Studio 1.5.x... File -> Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> System Settings

Answer (score 4):

Refer attached image for the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Now setting has changed in new Android Studio so might people face this problem to get where this setting is, so for your convenience i am enclosing screenshot here with.

[image]